# Trying to fill a Rust vector with objects using higher order function

Tags: vector, iterator, rust

I can create a Rust vector and fill it with struct instances using a loop, but I was wondering if I could get the same result using one of the higher order functions like `map` or such.

Here is some code that works:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct sim {
    id: i32,
}

impl Default for sim {
    fn default() -> sim {
        sim { id: 4 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v2 = Vec::<sim>::new();
    for i in 0..7 {
        v2.push(sim::default())
    }
    println!("{:?}", v2);
}
```

I tried the code below, but it did not work.

```
let mut v3 = Vec::<sim>::new();
(0..7).map(|| v3.push(sim::default()));
```

Comment: Note that idiomatic Rust style is to use `PascalCase` for types. `sim` is not correct, `Sim` would be. You also don't need to provide the type hint on `v2` — the fact that you push a `sim` is enough to infer the type.

Comment: Haha @Shepmaster thanks. I will get my minimal examples in shape one day here ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your immediate problem is: that isn't how `map` works *at all*.  Mapping involves taking a sequence and transforming each element in said sequence, producing a new sequence.  You *should not* be using it to just execute side effects for two reasons:

1. No one is going to *expect* you to do that, so your code will be more confusing than it should be to anyone else reading it.
2. Iterators in Rust are lazily computed, meaning that unless you consume the mapped iterator, nothing will happen.

If you really want to do something 7 times, *just use a loop*.  That's what they're `for`.  If you really, *desperately* need to do something like this, the [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate has a `foreach` method that does this whilst still communicating what's going on.

As to how to actually construct the collection using higher order functions...

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Sim {
    id: i32,
}

impl Default for Sim {
    fn default() -> Sim {
        Sim { id: 4 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    use std::iter;

    let v1 = vec![Sim::default(); 7];
    let v2: Vec<_> = iter::repeat(Sim::default()).take(7).collect();
    let v3: Vec<_> = (0..7).map(|_| Sim::default()).collect();
    let v4: Vec<_> = iter::once(Sim::default()).cycle().take(7).collect();
}
```

There are probably more.  Note that `v1`, `v2`, and `v4` require the item type to be `Clone` so that it can make copies.

Comment: *That's what they're `for`* — oh, I see what you did there.

Comment: Cool this is helpful. Yes I can write a loop, that is what I did first. I am just trying to understand the higher order functions in rust and get more comfortable with them. Thanks for the ideas as I would not have thought of these myself.